# Disabling desktop effects

Tags: effects

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.  Is there a way to disable all desktop effects at once?  I think that ability used to exist but I can't find it now, though I can go through the long list of them and disable each one individually.

Comment: If you are talking about the System Settings Module "Desktop Effects", AFAIK the only way you can change them all at once is the `Defaults` button at the bottom left of the window.  Otherwise you need to check/uncheck them individually.  Yes there's a lot but typically and hopefully you will only have to do it one time ever.

Comment: I believe thatg at one time there was a checkbox for "enable desktop effects", and unchecking it made them all go away.  That does not seem to be the case in Kubuntu 18.04.  Too bad!!